# How to change the key in angular forEach,and then i want push the data with the new key that i have changed?

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.forEach(res.deep_data,function(value,key){
    if(key == 'stock'){
        key = 'label';
        $scope.my_data.push(value);
    }
});
```

I want to change or replace the key in angular for Each and then I want to push the data's with the new key that changed?

I want to push the value with new key that I have changed.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide a code sample, we are unable to help without knowing what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the new key

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  key = 'new value';
  someArray.push(key);
});
```